# Customized tf.keras.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard does not work well in tensorflow version >= 1.15.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

The following customized TensorBoard, cloned from [this github repo](https://github.com/eyalzk/sketch_rnn_keras/blob/master/utils.py#L211), aiming to store learning rate and the so-called KL weight at the end of every batch, works very well in tensorflow version  <= 1.12.0, but does not do what it should at every batch in version >= 1.15.0. How can I fix it?

```
class TensorBoardLR(TensorBoard):
    """ A modification to the Tensorboard callback to also include the scalars of learning rate and KL weight"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.kl_weight = kwargs.pop('kl_weight')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.count = 0

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        logs.update({'lr': K.eval(self.model.optimizer.lr),
                     'kl_weight': K.eval(self.kl_weight)})
        super().on_batch_end(batch, logs)
```

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Comment: Does not record `lr` and `kl_weight` at every batch. Others are fine.

Comment: At some point they removed 'on_batch_end' and replaced it with 'on_train_batch_end' . For some of the metrics they've been replaced with averages, but I think the way you're logging that should **not** be an issue. edit: added not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of your method from `on_batch_end` to `on_train_batch_end`.

They kept the method for legacy code, https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback It is also a difference between keras, and tensorflow.keras.

Comment: Solved. Thank you.